# Android login system

Tags: android, sqlite

Im making a login system with sqlite for my app and I have login page.
After the user logged in successfully a new activity open.
My question is how I can find in the new activity who logged in.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your code. Otherwise, we can't know what you're doing.

Comment: I cant add the code now, but im just compare the username and the password from the user with what i have in the database if it ok im start new activity.

Comment: Just Google you get many example for sqlite login

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data from Login activity to the new activity like the username or any other data after the login is successful. In your case you can send the primary key of the logged in user to the activity and in the other activity you can query the details of the user based on the id.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityClass.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "ranjith");
intent.putExtra("id", "121212xxxdfd");
startActivity(intent);
```

In the Activity just retrieve the data as below:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (null != intent) {
    String name= intent.getStringExtra("name");
    String id=  intent.getStringExtra("id");  //db key
    Log.v("myapp","User logged in is "+ name);
  }
```